# Short script (<50 lines) works in jfiddle but not browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I was using a Horizontal-scrolling image gallery for a project.

Recently the scrolling stopped working, and I have been trying to figure out why. Eventually I decided to go back to the source of this part of the project and work up, but I can't even get it running.

I must be doing something simple wrong- any ideas?

[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SLN7/2/)

My Code:

HTML

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./waterfall3.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./waterfall.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="media">
<div class="imageContainer">
<div class="image"><a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a></div>
<div class="image"><a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a></div>
<div class="image"><a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a></div>    
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

JS

```
var imageWidth = 300;
$(".imageContainer").width($(".image").length*imageWidth);
```

CSS

```
.media
{
width: 300px; 
height: 288px; 
float: left;
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: auto;
-ms-overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.image
{
float: left;
height: 240px;
width: 300px;
margin: 0;
text-align:center;
border: 0px solid white;
}

.imageContainer
{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the console to see if you're missing any includes? Maybe jQuery or waterfall aren't in the specific folder ?

Comment: could be problem of `DOCTYPE` declaration.. 99% sure..

Comment: As you are requesting the DOM, you should wrap JS code inside DOM ready handler: `$(function () {
    $(".imageContainer").width($(".image").length * imageWidth);
});`

Comment: did you call your js in $(document).ready(function(){}) function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this js in your js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var imageWidth = 300;

    $(".imageContainer").width($(".image").length*imageWidth);
  });

</script>
```

this is work for me

http://jsfiddle.net/7SLN7/12/

see this demo

Comment: Sweet. I'll work back up from there. Could you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: it's important because your js code will be execute after your document is ready. otherwise your code will be execute before your document ready. @EtaiDKlein

Comment: Thanks! One more question....  I found that if I add any border to the .image or change the size, some images pop off the same line as the other divs. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the ***document*** to be loaded before executing your jQuery code:

```
//Wrapping your code in the document ready handler will fix your issue
$(function() {
    var imageWidth = 300;
    $(".imageContainer").width($(".image").length*imageWidth);
});
```

Read more about using [the document ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)